# Short exact sequence of free loop space fibration

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Consider the fibration $\Omega_0 M \to L_0M \to M$, where $M$ is a connected manifold and $\Omega_0M$ and $L_0M$ correspond to the (component of the contractible loop(s) of the) based loop space and the free loop space, respectively.

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02455.pdf), on page 11, the authors claim that it induces a short exact sequence
$$0 \to \pi_1(\Omega_0M) \to \pi_1(L_0M) \to \pi_1(M) \to 1, $$
with a section $s: \pi_1(M) \to \pi_1(L_0M)$ induced by the inclusion of $M$ as constant loops.

I may be missing something simple since this isn't explicitly explained there, but it is not clear to me why the map $i:\pi_1(\Omega_0M) \to \pi_1(L_0M)$ is injective, or equivalently why the rest of the long exact sequence of the fibration does not appear. There is no assumption in the paper that $\pi_2(M)=0$ (this assumption would actually conflict with some of its objectives), so I don't think it stems from that.

My question is: why is the above sequence exact?

Comment: In each dimension $e_*:\pi_n(L_0M)\rightarrow \pi_n(M)$ is surjective, since it has a splitting induced by the constants section $s:M\rightarrow L_0M$. Thus the long-exact homotopy sequence of the fibration breaks up into a collection of short-exact sequences.

Comment: lol actually the most confusing thing is starting with a zero and ending with a 1. I guess that this is because $\pi_1(\Omega M)$ is abelian?

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks! So it was just realizing that the section exists in the other dimensions. Could you please add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section $s$ actually exists as a continuous map, rather than only on the purely algebraic level. This is a special feature of the fact that you are considering the path-component $L_0M$ of the constant map $S^1\rightarrow M$ in the free loop space $LX=Map(S^1,M)$.

In more detail, if $M$ is a space, then the evaluation map $e:L_0M\rightarrow M$, $\lambda\mapsto\lambda(1)$, has a section section $s:M\rightarrow L_0M$ which sends a point $x\in M$ to the constant loop at $x$. Since $e\circ s=id_M$ the induced maps on homotopy groups satisfy $e_*s_*=(e\circ s)_*=id$. Thus if we consider the long-exact homotopy sequence of the fibration
$$\dots\rightarrow\pi_n(\Omega_0M)\xrightarrow{i_*} \pi_n(L_0M)\xrightarrow{e_*}\pi_n(M)\xrightarrow{\Delta}\pi_{n-1}\Omega_0(M)\rightarrow\dots$$
then $e_*$ is split surjective in each degree, so by exactness the connecting map $\Delta$ is always trivial, and $i_*:\pi_n\Omega_0M\rightarrow\pi_nL_0M$ is always injective. What results is a family of split short-exact sequences
$$0\rightarrow\pi_n(\Omega_0M)\xrightarrow{i_*} \pi_n(L_0M)\xrightarrow{e_*}\pi_n(M)\rightarrow0.$$